Create a basic server using NodeJS , Express, TypeScript and do the followinng in seperate apis respectively in same app.ts
PS E:\Nodejs Training\Project_1> npm run build

project_1@1.0.0 build
tsc

PS E:\Nodejs Training\Project_1> npm run start

project_1@1.0.0 start
node dist/node app.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Nodejs Training\Project_1\dist\node'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
Node.js v20.11.1
package.json
{
"name": "project_1",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/node app.js",
    "build": "tsc"
},
...}

Tried running the code from different directory not Working and also tried many different things also.

It looks like the start script in your package.json is wrong, please post its contents

{
"name": "project_1",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node dist/node app.js",
"build": "tsc"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"@types/express": "^4.17.21",
"@types/node": "^20.12.8",
"nodemon": "^3.1.0",
"ts-node": "^10.9.2",
"typescript": "^5.4.5"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.19.2"
}
}

"start": "node dist/node app.js"? I think it should be "start": "node ./dist/app.js"

I saw this in your package.json, Basically you are telling node to find something node which is inside dist/ (but it doesn't exist).
{
   ...
   "start": "node dist/node app.js"
   ...
}

When you run npm run build, It builds and puts the output into the ./dist directory, right? Then it should be,
{
   ...
   "start": "node ./dist/app.js"
   ...
}

